# Kubectl configuration in gcloud

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, gcloud

I created cluster in gcloud with three nodes. So far so good.Thereafter i tried to run the pod.. it is giving error.. I found out the kubectl is not configured correct.. Getting following error when I try to run the pod.. Appreciate any help in this regard.

error: could not read an encoded object from nodejs.yaml: unable to connect to a server to handle "pods": couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your kubectl configuration is incorrect after creating a cluster, you can always run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME` (see [configuring kubectl](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/operations#configuring_kubectl)) to restore a working kubeconfig file.

Comment: Thanks Robert.. that helped.. Actually I was trying to run the pod from cloud vm.. that was the first problem.  Once I started firing these commands from outside linux machine it started behaving good.. Thanks for your help..

Comment: What OS were you using on the cloud VM?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)

Comment: I just created a new Debian Wheezy VM (on Google's cloud) and didn't see any problems. Running `gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME` prompted me to install kubectl locally (by running `gcloud components update kubectl`) and other than the fact that kubectl wasn't on my path (it was in `/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl`) I was able to create a replication controller and a service without any trouble.